# Why the reactive form validation cause "Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined"?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My code is resided in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2znam?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

I want to bind CallTreeEntry object the form.

I want to divide the form into 3 form group.

1. One for the CallTreeEntry attributes,
2. One for the CallTree object
3. One for the Manual object

So, I can validate the above object individually.

However, I get the following error message when reloading the web page.

```
ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
```

When I remove the following code, the error message vanishes.

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="division.errors">
    Division Name is <strong>required</strong>
  </mat-error>
```

And I refer [the Form validation page of Angular web site](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).

I added the following function the code, however, it doesn't work.

```
get name() { 
   return this.callTreeEntryForm.get('name'); 
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code to the question in addition to the (helpful) stackblitz link

Comment: Put a [mre] *in the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `mat-error` conditional statement. You cannot check the value like this.
If you want to display error if the form control is valid, you need to change the error condition.

Please use the below in your template (HTML):

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="attributes.controls['division'].hasError('required')">
    Division Name is <strong>required</strong>
  </mat-error>
```

Please let me know if need any help.